# How exactly do kernel virtual addresses get translated to physical RAM?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

On the surface, this appears to be a silly question. Some patience please.. :-)
Am structuring this qs into 2 parts:

**Part 1:**
I fully understand that platform RAM is mapped into the kernel segment; esp on 64-bit systems this will work well. So each kernel virtual address is indeed just an offset from physical memory (DRAM).

Also, it's my understanding that as Linux is a modern virtual memory OS, (pretty much) *all* addresses are treated as virtual addresses and must "go" via hardware - the TLB/MMU - at runtime and then get  translated by the TLB/MMU via kernel paging tables. Again, easy to understand for user-mode processes.

HOWEVER, what about kernel virtual addresses? For efficiency, would it not be simpler to direct-map these (and an identity mapping is indeed setup from PAGE_OFFSET onwards). But still, at runtime, the kernel virtual address ***must*** go via the TLB/MMU and get translated right??? Is this actually the case? Or is kernel virtual addr translation just an offset calculation?? (But how can that be, as we *must* go via hardware TLB/MMU?). As a simple example, lets consider:

```
char *kptr = kmalloc(1024, GFP_KERNEL);
```

Now kptr is a kernel virtual address. 
I understand that virt_to_phys() can perform the offset calculation and return the physical DRAM address. 
But, *here's the Actual Question*: it can't be done in this manner via software - that would be pathetically slow! So, back to my earlier point: it would have to be translated via hardware (TLB/MMU). 
*Is this actually the case??*

**Part 2:**
Okay, lets say this is the case, and we do use paging in the kernel to do this, we must of course setup kernel paging tables; I understand it's rooted at swapper_pg_dir.

(I also understand that vmalloc() unlike kmalloc() is a special case- it's  a pure virtual region that gets backed by physical frames only on page fault).

If (in Part 1) we do conclude that kernel virtual address translation is done via kernel paging tables, then how exactly does the kernel paging table (swapper_pg_dir) get "attached" or "mapped" to a user-mode process?? This should happen in the context-switch code? How? Where?

Eg.
On an x86_64, 2 processes A and B are alive, 1 cpu.
A is running, so it's higher-canonical addr
`0xFFFF8000 00000000 through 0xFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF`  "map" to the kernel segment, and it's lower-canonical addr
`0x0 through 0x00007FFF FFFFFFFF`   map to it's private userspace.

Now, if we context-switch A->B, process B's lower-canonical region is unique But
it must "map" to the same kernel of course!
How exactly does this happen? How do we "auto" refer to the kernel paging table when
in kernel mode? Or is that a wrong statement?

Thanks for your patience, would really appreciate a well thought out answer!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First a bit of background.

This is an area where there is a lot of potential variation between
architectures, however the original poster has indicated he is mainly
interested in x86 and ARM, which share several characteristics:

- no hardware segments or similar partitioning of the virtual address space (when used by Linux)
- hardware page table walk
- multiple page sizes
- physically tagged caches (at least on modern ARMs)

So if we restrict ourselves to those systems it keeps things simpler.

Once the MMU is enabled, it is never normally turned off. So all CPU
addresses are virtual, and will be translated to physical addresses
using the MMU. The MMU will first look up the virtual address in the
TLB, and only if it doesn't find it in the TLB will it refer to the
page table - the TLB is a cache of the page table - and so we can
ignore the TLB for this discussion.

The page table
describes the entire virtual 32 or 64 bit address space, and includes
information like:

- whether the virtual address is valid
- which mode(s) the processor must be in for it to be valid
- special attributes for things like memory mapped hardware registers
- and the physical address to use

Linux divides the virtual address space into two: the lower portion is
used for user processes, and there is a different virtual to physical
mapping for each process. The upper portion is used for the kernel,
and the mapping is the same even when switching between different user
processes. This keep things simple, as an address is unambiguously in
user or kernel space, the page table doesn't need to be changed when
entering or leaving the kernel, and the kernel can simply dereference
pointers into user space for the 
current user process. Typically on 32bit processors the split is 3G
user/1G kernel, although this can vary. Pages for the kernel portion
of the address space will be marked as accessible only when the processor
is in kernel mode to prevent them being accessible to user processes.
The portion of the kernel address space which is identity mapped to RAM
(kernel logical addresses) will be mapped using big pages when possible,
which may allow the page table to be smaller but more importantly
reduces the number of TLB misses.

When the kernel starts it creates a single page table for itself
(`swapper_pg_dir`) which just describes the kernel portion of the
virtual address space and with no mappings for the user portion of the
address space. Then every time a user process is created a new page
table will be generated for that process, the portion which describes
kernel memory will be the same in each of these page tables. This could be
done by copying all of the relevant portion of `swapper_pg_dir`, but
because page tables are normally a tree structures, the kernel is
frequently able to graft the portion of the tree which describes the
kernel address space from `swapper_pg_dir` into the page tables for each
user process by just copying a few entries in the upper layer of the
page table structure. As well as being more efficient in memory (and possibly
cache) usage, it makes it easier to keep the mappings consistent. This
is one of the reasons why the split between kernel and user virtual
address spaces can only occur at certain addresses.

To see how this is done for a particular architecture look at the
implementation of `pgd_alloc()`. For example ARM
([arch/arm/mm/pgd.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/pgd.c)) uses:

```
pgd_t *pgd_alloc(struct mm_struct *mm)
{
    ...
    init_pgd = pgd_offset_k(0);
    memcpy(new_pgd + USER_PTRS_PER_PGD, init_pgd + USER_PTRS_PER_PGD,
               (PTRS_PER_PGD - USER_PTRS_PER_PGD) * sizeof(pgd_t));
    ...
}
```

or
x86 ([arch/x86/mm/pgtable.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/mm/pgtable.c)) `pgd_alloc()` calls `pgd_ctor()`:

```
static void pgd_ctor(struct mm_struct *mm, pgd_t *pgd)
{
    /* If the pgd points to a shared pagetable level (either the
       ptes in non-PAE, or shared PMD in PAE), then just copy the
       references from swapper_pg_dir. */
        ...
        clone_pgd_range(pgd + KERNEL_PGD_BOUNDARY,
                swapper_pg_dir + KERNEL_PGD_BOUNDARY,
                KERNEL_PGD_PTRS);
    ...
}
```

So, back to the original questions:

**Part 1**: Are kernel virtual addresses really translated by the TLB/MMU?

Yes.

**Part 2**: How is `swapper_pg_dir` "attached" to a user mode process.

All page tables (whether `swapper_pg_dir` or those for user processes)
have the same mappings for the portion used for kernel virtual
addresses. So as the kernel context switches between user processes,
changing the current page table, the mappings for the kernel portion
of the address space remain the same.

Comment: This is a really great answer. I had the same question going through the Memory Management chapter of @kaiwan 's elaborate _Linux Kernel Programming_ book.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel address space is mapped to a section of each process for example on 3:1 mapping after address 0xC0000000. If the user code try to access this address space it will generate a page fault and it is guarded by the kernel. 
The kernel address space is divided into 2 parts, the logical address space and the virtual address space. It is defined by the constant VMALLOC_START. The CPU is using the MMU all the time, in user space and in kernel space (can't switch on/off). 
The kernel virtual address space is mapped the same way as user space mapping. The logical address space is continuous and it is simple to translate it to physical so it can be done on demand using the MMU fault exception. That is the kernel is trying to access an address, the MMU generate fault , the fault handler map the page using macros __pa , __va and change the CPU pc register back to the previous instruction before the fault happened, now everything is ok. This process is actually platform dependent and in some hardware architectures it mapped the same way as user (because the kernel doesn't use a lot of memory).

Comment: Thanks Liran. By logical address space I assume you mean the direct-mapped DRAM region. So in effect you're saying that for the logical region, the kernel 'fixes' the phy addr via page fault handling and does _not_ lookup kernel paging table (which implies we don;t have to change the CR3 / TTBRn register value)?
And only for vmalloc faults does the kernel paging tables actually get used?

Comment: My understanding is that we only (page) fault in kernel-space for the vmalloc & exception fixups (like copy_to|from_user). Any other fault in kernel-mode is a bug and an Oops occurs..

Comment: Yes. Exactly, that's how it's done in most architectures. (Linux supports 21 hardware arch and its arch specific so maybe in one it is done differently)

Comment: If possible, I'd prefer details for x86_64 and ARM, thanks

Comment: in x86 its like i wrote but on 64 bit the kernel address space is the upper 2GB. On ARM you can set the kernel address space using kernel configuration (kernel features) to 3:1/2:2/1:3 so in some embedded systems if you need more kernel memory you can set it up to 3GB. the translation of logical address done on x86/ARM as described above

Comment: No, I don't think that's right. As I mentioned earlier, "only [valid] (page) fault in kernel-space [is] for the vmalloc & exception fixups (like copy_to|from_user). Any other fault in kernel-mode is a bug and an Oops occurs". 
Code view: x86 case: seeing kernel src v 4.5 here [http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L1294] on page fault we have:
do_page_fault -> __do_page_fault ->  (calls)
... if (unlikely(fault_in_kernel_space(address))) ...

[No space left in this comment so continuing in the next comment]

Comment: This handles the vmalloc & any other special fixup case, else invoking bad_area_nosemaphore() which invokes an Oops.
So, just saying, I don't think the fault code path handles kernel virtual address translation..

Comment: The TLB especially on ARM processors is very small. TI proc. has 32 entries in the CPU TLB so after using 128kb of RAM its full and then if we use more there are a lot of TLB flushes. This is happening in the kernel and in user by using MMU fault mechanism. There is no point to save all the logical address space pages in the TLB because it will just increase the faults number so it's better to do the translation on demand.